# When using the Mongodump shell, how do you specify the database and collection from a replica set?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I need to create a mongodump of a specific collection from a specific database in a replica set.  I am issuing the following command from the windows command shell:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://dd-domain-dev-shard-0-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-1-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-2-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017/?replicaSet=dd-domain-dev-shard-0" --db=TargetDatabase_dev --collection=abcCollection
```

When doing so, the following error occurs:

```
error parsing command line options: illegal argument combination: cannot specify --db and --uri
```

How can I create an acceptable command that includes both the database and collection?  I must specify both because the replica set contains several databases, and I only want that single collection in the output file.

MongoDb version: 4.2.11
MongoDump version: r4.0.1

Comment: just remove `--uri`

Comment: @Minsky if I do that, mondodump tries to connect to my local instance of MongoDb

Answer (score 4):

Include the database name in the URI.

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://dd-domain-dev-shard-0-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-1-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-2-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017/TargetDatabase_dev?replicaSet=dd-domain-dev-shard-0"  --collection=abcCollection
```

If that doesn't work:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://dd-domain-dev-shard-0-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-1-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-2-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017/TargetDatabase_dev?replicaSet=dd-domain-dev-shard-0&authSource=admin"  --collection=abcCollection
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct but you will need to include most options in the `--uri` string.

If you want to keep those as dashed options  (`--option`) you can do it
by using `--host` instead.

```
mongodump --host="dd-domain-dev-shard-0/dd-domain-dev-shard-0-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-1-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-2-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017" --db=TargetDatabase_dev 
--collection=abcCollection
```

You will probably need to authenticate though, like so

```
mongodump --host="dd-domain-dev-shard-0/dd-domain-dev-shard-0-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-1-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017,dd-domain-dev-shard-2-abcde.azure.mongodb.net:27017/" --db=TargetDatabase_dev --collection=abcCollection --authenticationDatabase admin -u <username> -p <password>
```

[Here is the relevant MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/index.html#cmdoption-mongodump-uri)